# flutter dart sdk version

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, sdk

Flutter doctor all good.
My pubspe.yaml.
[image]

My terminal Problem.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change dart sdk version in `pubspec.yaml` to following,

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.6 <3.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

this two command solved my problem:

```
flutter channel master
flutter upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need dart SDK version 2.18 and above? If not, just update your pubspec.yaml accordingly:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.6 <3.0.0"
```